How to pass data to layout.jsx from children in NextJs 14?
I have created group routes in my NextJs 14 application, it has a layout.jsx which has the following code:


 export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (  
    <main
      className={clsx(
        "d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center",
        styles.registration
      )}
    >
      <div className={clsx("d-flex flex-column p-4 p-md-5", styles.card)}>
        <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center position-relative">
          <button className={clsx("position-absolute", styles.backButton)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowLeft} />
          </button>
          <div className={clsx(styles.logoContainer)}>
            <Image src="/logo-wingtrill.svg" priority fill alt="Wingtrill" />
          </div>
        </div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}



So the layout.jsx has the back button which will be used for navigating to the previous route but I can only define the back route in the children itself because only here I know what will be th previous route so how do I pass the back route from children to this root layout for the back button.
I tried to print the children which gave me this


 {
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function (anonymous)],
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {
    parallelRouterKey: 'children',
    segmentPath: [ 'children', '(registration)', 'children' ],
    error: undefined,
    errorStyles: undefined,
    errorScripts: undefined,
    template: {
      '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
      type: Symbol(react.fragment),
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: [Object],
      _owner: null,
      _store: {}
    },
    templateStyles: undefined,
    templateScripts: undefined,
    notFound: {
      '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
      type: [Function],
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: {},
      _owner: null,
      _store: {}
    },
    notFoundStyles: [],
    styles: null
  },
  _owner: null,
  _store: {}
}



Nothing was usefull in this.  I am new to NextJs. Any help will be appreciated.
